# Change label text from variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to write a program that has twenty five buttons, when one is pressed, it will read from a text file, store it in a variable, then make the text of the label at the bottom of the page change to the text of the text file. Here is my code so far:

```
from Tkinter import*
box1 = 'C:/Users/Geekman2/Documents/Tests/box1.txt'
var = StringVar()
var.set("man")
def openfile(filename):
    filetxt = (open(filename,"r").read())
   #filetxt.set(iletxt)
    print filetxt
    return filetxt

def Box1():
    openfile(box1)


openfile(box1)
donut = Tk()
donut.geometry('450x450')

cupcake = Button(donut,text = "Box #1", command= Box1 )
cupcake.pack()

Whatsin = Label(donut,textvariable = var)
Whatsin.pack(side =BOTTOM)

donut.mainloop()
```

These two lines are giving me trouble, whenever I uncomment them and try to run the program I get the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'"

```
var = Stringvar()
var.set("man")
```

Can anyone tell me what might be the cause of this? I know what the error means, but as far as I can tell it doesn't apply in this situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate an instance of `Tk` before you can use `StringVar`.  Move `donut = Tk()` before your lines and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

StringVar (as well as other Tkinter variable) are wrappers around Tcl variable<sup>1</sup>.
Your error come from creating a StringVar before the Tcl interpreter is initialized.

Thus you might call `Tk()`(which perform such initialisation) before creating your variables.

If you look at StringVar constructor signature: `__init__(self, master=None, value=None, name=None)` you see that as other Tkinter objects, the constructor accepts a `master` as first argument. This master is essentially needed to access the Tcl interpreter. If not provided, there is a fallback to a global `Tkinter.Tk` instance `_default_root`, which is `None` in your case. Asking the Tcl interpreter (field named `tk`) on it raise the `AttributeError`.

Note that for widgets, not providing master lead to the creation of a default one, but not on variables.

<sup>1</sup> the whole Tkinter toolkit is a wrapper around a Tcl toolkit called Tk. Tcl variables allow to be *traced*, ie bind callback on variable change. Tk heavily use this mechanism and thus, Tkinter has to provide access to Tcl variables.